# Subtracting DC Offset a Complex Signal?

Tags: image-processing, preprocessing

If I take the magnitude of a complex signal, and then subtract the mean amplitude, I remove DC offset but lose the real and imaginary components. How can I properly subtract the DC offset of a complex signal? Subtracting the complex amplitude results in a non-zero magnitude so I don't believe that's the way to go...

Answer (score 3):

Using the term "DC offset" is a little misleading in this context.  I think what you are asking is how do your "center" your signal.  That is simple:  Take the average value (sum of N samples divided by N) and subtract it from each sample.  A "DC offset" is usually considered in terms of real valued signals.  The DC stands for "Direct Current".

Comment: for complex baseband signals, would you take the magnitude first? I think that is the gist of the question.

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 I didn't read it that way, but maybe.  The question isn't that clear.  My answer is really more one of clarifying the terminology while answering.  It's a 2+ year old question.

Comment: yeah agree the question isn’t totally clear. My follow up comment came bc I had a similar question. If you wanted to account for the “DC”, or mean offset, of a complex baseband signal, would the mean be of complex valued samples or the mean of the absolute value of the complex valued samples?

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 The zero frequency bin in a DFT has the sum of the samples in an unnormalized DFT and average/mean with a (1/N) normalization.  For a complex signal it may be complex, hence calling it DC is a misnomer.  For real valued signals the DC and Nyquits (even N) bins will always be real, i.e. imaginary part is zero.  This is a direct result of the conjugate symmetry real signals have in the DFT.  Note, that it may be negative.